# Dynamic menu class assignment in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a secondary nav bar that allows a user to move between various aspects of their account.

DASHBOARD | ACTIVITY | PORTFOLIO | PROJECTS

I want to have the CSS of the current_page be bold so that when the user is on the 'dashboard' the nav bar looks like this:

**DASHBOARD** | ACTIVITY | PORTFOLIO | PROJECTS

I have been fiddling with

```
if current_page?(controller: 'users', action: 'edit)
  <span class="bold">DASHBOARD</span>
else
  DASHBOARD
end
```

and similar code, but it's not working.  The reason is the nested partials that I'm using to generate the views.

For example, a user can only bring up their own account information, but since each user can have many projects, I'm rendering a call to a partial under `views/projects/_list_by_owner.html.erb`, and passing in

`@projects = Project.where(:owner_id => current_user.id)` from the `users_controller#show`.

Since the view is being generated from the `users_controller` and not the `projects_controller`, it's not picking up the correct `current_page()`.

Any ideas on how to dig deeper into the controller/action nesting, or maybe a better way of generating the css class dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres what i would do

**Helper class**

```
def currentp(path)
  "bold" if request.url.include?(path)
end
```

**View**

```
<%= link_to "users", posts_path, class: currentp(posts_path) %>
```

**EDIT:** Adding explanation

Use helpers if you're working in a view (template) and you need to build a complex bit of HTML such as a  or even defining a class. It also allows you to change the presentation of data without connecting to the database.

So under App >> helpers >> users_helper.rb

add the following code:

```
module LocationsHelper
    def currentp(path)
        "bold" if request.url.include?(path)
    end
end
```

This will find wherever the `currentp` is called and if the page is on the current path, it will define the class within the html to be `bold`.

Then you can use simple css to define the bold class

```
a.bold{
  font-weight:700;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: It's not quite what I need, but I'll play with it and try and make it work.  If I can, I'll accept your answer and post the final code below.

Comment: @Matteo Just updated my post with a more up-to-date explanation